# Python- How do I combine two outputs and merge them so what prints is a single value? python 2.7

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, readlines

So basically I have this code:

```
try:
    fhanddate = open('AAPLprice.txt')

except:
    print 'Could not open file - closing application'
    exit()

stock_date = []

for line in fhanddate:
    p = line.strip()
    q = p.split(',')
    r = q[0:]

    stock_date.append(r)

for line in stock_date:
    pass
last = line
print last[0]

try:
    fhanda = open('AAPLprice.txt')
except:
    print 'Could not open file - closing application'
    exit()

stock_priceA = []

for line in fhanda:
    p = line.strip()
    q = p.split(',')
    r = q[-1:]
    stock_priceA.append(r)

print max(stock_priceA)
```

My output as a result is :

```
2015-07-21    
['129.606052']
```

So I want to know how I can combine both of these outputs so I get : 2015-07-21 129.606052 , as a result

When I try to just combine them I get the "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects" error

Comment: I think this is Python2? Also, could you include a sample of AAPLprice.txt? E.g. what the lines look like?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes 2.7

Comment: How are you trying to combine the string and list? You can concatenate them together if you turn the list into a string first using str(list)

Comment: there are a lot of things to do with lines above.  but simply put `,` after your first print statement and `[0]` after last.

Comment: Is there a certain reason you print the first column of the final line and the max value from the second column? Are all the first column values the same?

Comment: a = 2015-07-21
b = ['lol']

print a,str(b)

You can cast your list to a string, to concatenate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply join them together with a "+":

```
a = 2015-07-21 
b = ['129.606052']
print a + b[0]
```

`b[0]` takes the first item in the list, `b`. In this case, it takes out the only item in the list. You can add a space by simply adding a string in between them:

```
print a + " " + b[0]
```